# Retrieving variable with message

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to retrieve variable to display along with message this way. but, i came to know this actually is not a way. `$count` is the variable to be displayed along with message.

```
   public function now(Request $request)
      {
            $name=$request->get('name');
            $contact=$request->get('contact');
            $level=$request->get('level');

            $count=$level*3.5;
            return redirect('/lost')
                    ->with ('message','You have increased your level to $count.');
        }
```

Comment: Just change `with ('message','You have increased your level to $count.');` to `with ('message',"You have increased your level to $count.");` (double quotes instead of single)

Comment: Which framework you are using ?In most of the framework there is inbuilt flash message session variable .

Comment: @ Thamilan. oh thanks. i didn't think it was that easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
with ('message','You have increased your level to $count.');
```

to

```
with ('message',"You have increased your level to $count.");
```

(double quotes instead of single)

You may see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) to know the difference

Answer (score 1):

This will work :

**PHP**

```
   public function now(Request $request)
   {
         $name=$request->get('name');
         $contact=$request->get('contact');
         $level=$request->get('level');

         $count=$level*3.5;
         return redirect('/lost')
                 ->with ('message','You have increased your level to ' . $count . ' .');
     }
```